# how to convert videos into frames with openCV python?

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')
success,image = vidcap.read()
count = 0
success = True
while success:
  success,image = vidcap.read()
  print 'Read a new frame: ', success
  cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % count, image)     # save frame as JPEG file
  count += 1
```

I am getting 'False' for success in this code. The while loop gets executed for only once. Cannot split the video into frames.
What is the problem in the code?

Comment: Use `cv2.waitKey()`

Comment: See [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15870612/saving-an-image-sequence-from-video-using-opencv2)

Comment: Also see [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900637/problems-converting-video-to-pictures-using-python-2-7)